# Flutter Hot Reload Does not remove old content

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I just started out with Flutter, but I am experiencing a weird bug. When I make a change and flutter hot reloads it works however it does not remove the old content. So if I have a single string on my app and move it before a hot reload it looks like this:

[image]

I can't seem to find a good term to Google a solution to solve this. Does anyone have a good Google term for me to Google this problem? (Or maybe a link/solution for me to solve it?)

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
        width: 48.0,
        height: 48.0,
        child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Text(
              "Hello world!!",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1)),
            )));
  }
}
```

System: Windows 10
Editer: VS Code
Emulator Android 10 on Nexus 6p

Comment: You may share your code to help us understand what happens

Comment: @FPerroch I have added the code - thank you.

Comment: Sry but your code is unusable in that state

Comment: I have tested the code on dartpad. There is no issue, it works as expected. I have changed the values of margin and it redraws the whole thing.